# Where is the GNOME Text Editor's spelling dictionary stored?

Tags: 22.10, spell-checking, gnome-text-editor

I mistakenly clicked at the **Add to Dictionary** menu option for a wrongly typed word in *GNOME Text Editor 43.1* and now every such a word is considered "correct" by `gnome-text-editor`. How can I remove that word from the user-defined spelling dictionary of GNOME Text Editor?

After doing some research, I found out that `gnome-text-editor` uses *enchant* for spell checking. I searched in my home directory and found that the configuration directory named `~/.config/enchant/` contains some files like `en_US.dic` that *did* contain my added words. I removed the line containing my wrong word and later I even deleted all the files in this directory. But, still `gnome-text-editor` treats my wrong word as correctly spelled. I also tried to log out and log back in and restart my computer in case some memory resident process is still running. But, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that `aspell` (a tool used by `enchant`) is also storing the same word(s) inside the file `~/.aspell.en.pws`. I deleted that file together with another one called `~/.aspell.en.prepl` and the problem has gone now.

Some additional info about these files:

`~/.aspell.en.pws` is the personal word list for the Aspell spell checker in English. It contains a list of words (one per line) that are specific to a user and are not found in the default English dictionary.

`~/.aspell.en.prepl` is the personal replacement list for the Aspell spell checker in English. It contains a list of common misspellings and their corrections.